# How to create field through func in openerp?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have created a button oin my custom openerp module. I wanted to add func to this button to create a field. I have added the function but how to add functionality for creating fields . please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create field on function, you have to create field in object 'ir.model.fields'

if you are create simple field like float. char, boolean then you have to give value Field Name, Label, Model, for which object you want to create field , if many2one or many2many field then you have to give Object Relation field to.

Hope this help

Comment: if I want to create a field thrugh this function and the leave the features of field to admin. Like when he click add button then he can set field name ,data type etc by himself. Can this be done ?

Comment: then you have to open ir,model.fields object form view on button click

Comment: then on button click you have to return 'ir.model.fields' form and action.

Comment: means I can return 'ir.model.fields'  in my func which is being called on button press .